# Microsoft Access Number Field with letters

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Currently, I am creating a Database and ran into trouble with my tables.

I have a `tblCustomer` which includes a `CustomerID` that is an `autonumber` with the format of `Customer-001`, however I have a `tblOrder` for customer ordering and there is a one to many relationships between this.
I have an `orderID` field with an `autonumber` with the format `Order-001`. The problem is with the `customerID` in this table, its data type is a `number` but I used a lookup in order to get the `CustomerID` from `tblCustomer` in order to add to the table `Order`. Due to the format being `Customer-001` there are letters within in this and due to this, there is an error due to data types.

Comment: If you can't adjust the tables to use the existing key, you could create a mapping table where the existing key gets a unique numeric id and map them accordingly.

I'd try to reconcile now while you are building it, though.

Comment: In the database for the format of the autonumbers it has to include letters with it. The customer-001 works as an autonumber but it wont work in the other tables when i use the lookup. It would be easier for me to have everything just numeric but unfortunately for the task that i have to do it must include characters too

Comment: Two pieces of advice: don't use a mixed format like that for ID columns (especially with a "-" embedded like that), and avoid auto-numbers. You ideally want to tie things like customer numbers and order numbers to something in the real world. You're going to run into a world of trouble doing it this way.

Comment: So can you fix the customerID in tblOrder? Make them the same.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to convert it to a short text format? This way i have to manually enter the ID's but in other tables use lookup to add the ID to it

Comment: Ditto @Pat. Try to design for optimal minimalism, but yes, this.

Comment: This is what my tables look like: https://gyazo.com/5a88aa7c4e56066cf394529ff3d7922b https://gyazo.com/ff527a6c55f41495f1fb2f25c636eece

Comment: I see that one has a "-" and the other doesn't. More importantly, from the standpoint of joining the tables, there isn't a compelling reason to have "CC" or "Customer" in the join column. If you need to have them in the front end forms or reports for end user requirements, handle it there. For the purpose of efficiently joining tables, just use numbers.

Comment: I thought if i had the autonumbers it would make the database more efficient when entering data as you do not have to manually enter the Customer ID's and Order ID's

Comment: @Pat, its part of a school assignment and the teacher said that for extra marks it would be ideal to add things such as the format of autonumbers

Comment: It is a debate with at least two sides, but there is a good discussion [here](https://www.clever-cloud.com/blog/engineering/2015/05/20/why-auto-increment-is-a-terrible-idea/) as to why you would want to avoid serial primary keys and opt for either a UUID, or something tied physically to the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a customer number to look like this "Customer-001", you can still use a numeric field in the database and just format the number like this for display.

In the Access Immediate window (open with Ctrl-G):

```
?Format$(1, """Customer-""000")
```

yields the output

> Customer-001

In the `Format` field of an Access TextBox you would fill in `"Customer-"000`.

Never store `Customer-001` in the DB and never use `Customer-001` for joining or querying. In Access autonumber columns are of type `Number / Long Integer`.

If you want `Customer-001`, you would query

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE CustomerID = 1
```

And

```
Dim id as Long
id = DLookup("CustomerID", "tblCustomer", "CustomerName='Miller'")
```

Yields `1` (or another `Long` value) for the `id`, no matter how the `Format` property for that column was set.

I.e. the format (unlike the column type) does not matter in where clauses an join operations.

You would insert the customer in the orders table like this

```
INSERT INTO tblOrder (CustomerID, othercolumns)
VALUES (1, othervalues)
```

NOT `VALUES ('1', othervalues)` or `VALUES ('Customer-001', othervalues)`

---

I made a test. My table looks like this (Access 2002):
[image]

This is how it looks in my Access 2002 before entering something:
[image]

While entering `CustomerID`:
[image]

After entering `CustomerID` while being in the date field:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful response, looks like it will work but im not sure how to work the window that pops up when i press Ctrl-G. I pasted that into the immediate box at the bottom. What do i do after?

Comment: Enter `?Format$(1, """Customer-""000")` and press the `Enter` key. The `? ...` is a synomym for `Debug.Print( ... )`

Comment: in the access file when i try to add the customer id it is still coming up that there is a data value error when i do this.

Comment: 1. How are you trying to add the customer id exacly? 2. What is the type of the corresponding foreign key column (in `tblOrder`). 3. Is it an Access table or a MySQL table?

Comment: I have a Customer Table which has CustomerID within it which is an autonumber, it comes within the format of Customer-001 which increments but then i have an Order Table which has an OrderID as an autonumber and has CustomerID as a foreign key, i used a lookup check to add the Customer ID into this table from the Customer Table if this makes sense.  Here are a few screenshots if they help. ERD Relationship - https://gyazo.com/9a0df458c4ce1bdf833c5727fd3afd62  Customer Table - https://gyazo.com/19c333ece22085d3305a747d3dde31ca  Order Table -https://gyazo.com/8bb735d8d5d9a869194d730959a1ff1c

Comment: Yes, but this does not explain the error. How are you trying to add the order exactly? Manually, programmatically in VBA, with a query? Show the exact code and queries you are using (edit your question and add the code there). The error must be there somewhere.

Comment: Im entering Data manually on the database, i currently dont have queries in the database, im just working on setting the tables up. Im looking the customer ID field in the Order table to output in the format of "CC-001". However there is an error due to letters being mixed with numbers as it is a number data type but i dont get why it doesnt work as it works with autonumbers.

Comment: No matter how it is displayed, always enter `1` manually. You cannot enter  `CC-001` or `Customer-001`. This does not work as the column is numeric. After entering `1` it will automatically be displayed as formatted.

Comment: This is what it looks like in my Order Table when i use lookup to get the customer Id. https://gyazo.com/35a451d3c682f1d50c9853fd6556ccc0             Are you saying that there is no way to get it to display like this in the table

Comment: I made a test and added pictures. I didn't get any errors.

Comment: This is very weird, is there anyway i can send you my database? if you choose to have a look ive uploaded to dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbgjk2fkfwb5p52/CityCatalgoue1_Backup.accdb?dl=0  .. i really appreciate the help you've provided

Comment: This works for me. Of course I have to enter 3 for the CustomerID in tblOrder, since there is only a customer with Id=3 in tblCustomer. You cannot enter non-existant customer ids in the foreign key column.

Comment: Entering 3 works weirdly enough, how come if you use the lookup it provides and error as in the form it was going to be a lookup to be used to get customer ids

Comment: If you want to use a `ComboBox` as lookup, the first column must be `CustomerID`. Its width can then be `0cm` to hide it, if you prefer. The ComboBox properties are: Control Source: `CustomerID`, Row Source (example): `SELECT CustomerID, Format(CustomerID, '"CC-"000') & ' ' & Surname & ' ' & Forename FROM tblCustomer ORDER BY Surname;`. BoundColumn: `1`, Limit To List: `Yes`. Column Count: `2`, Column Widths: `0cm`. I.e. use unformatted ID for binding and formatted for display.